# Python AST - How to see value of assign node?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

For example, I'm visiting an assignment and I'm currently keeping track of the # of assignments I see. What I want to do is also keep track of what has been on the LHS of the assignment operator to see what has already been assigned prior in the program.

```
class counter(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.assign = 0

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)
        self.assign += 1
```

Say in my file I have

```
x = 5
```

When I visit this assignment, how do I print the value on the LHS of the assignment operator? I've tried print(node.value) and that did not work. My goal is to keep track of all the variables that have been assigned in my program.