# How do I use Python AST module to obtain all targets and value for assignment nodes?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Similar unanswered question: [Python AST - How to see value of assign node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876896/python-ast-how-to-see-value-of-assign-node)

I am trying to obtain the assignments statements in a file. Example:

```
def isMaskedArray(x): ...
isarray = isMaskedArray
masked_array = MaskedArray

_ShapeType = TypeVar("_ShapeType", bound=Any)
```

```
Module(
  body=[
    FunctionDef(
      name='isMaskedArray',     
      args=arguments(
        posonlyargs=[],
        args=[arg(
          arg='x',
          annotation=None,      
          type_comment=None)],  
        vararg=None,
        kwonlyargs=[],
        kw_defaults=[],
        kwarg=None,
        defaults=[]),
      body=[Expr(value=Constant(
        value=Ellipsis,
        kind=None))],
      decorator_list=[],
      returns=None,
      type_comment=None),
    Assign(
      targets=[Name(
        id='isarray',
        ctx=Store())],
      value=Name(
        id='isMaskedArray',
        ctx=Load()),
      type_comment=None),
    Assign(
      targets=[Name(
        id='masked_array',
        ctx=Store())],
      value=Name(
        id='MaskedArray',
        ctx=Load()),
      type_comment=None),
    Assign(
      targets=[Name(
        id='_ShapeType',
        ctx=Store())],
      value=Call(
        func=Name(
          id='TypeVar',
          ctx=Load()),
        args=[Constant(
          value='_ShapeType',
          kind=None)],
        keywords=[keyword(
          arg='bound',
          value=Name(
            id='Any',
            ctx=Load()))]),
      type_comment=None)],
  type_ignores=[])
```

and form them into a dictionary like so:

```
[{isarray: isMaskedArray}, {masked_array: MaskedArray}]
```

I only want the Assigns with value and target, no call objects. The AST module is very difficult to understand and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your dictionary contains strings? Or an ast Node(`Name`) object?

Comment: I would like it to be strings please @AbdulNiyasPM

Comment: I just want to extract what target is assigned to what value and place it in a dictionary format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ast.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.walk). This will recursively yield all descendant nodes. You can then check if the node is an instance of [`ast.Assign`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.Assign), if yes, it has `targets` and `value` attributes which contains the details you are looking for.

```
>>> import ast
>>>
>>> tree = ast.parse(source)
>>>
>>> result = {
...     node.targets[0].id: node.value.id
...     for node in ast.walk(tree)
...     if isinstance(node, ast.Assign)
... }
>>>
>>> print(result)
{'isarray': 'isMaskedArray', 'masked_array': 'MaskedArray'}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, but do you mind explaining it? I am not sure how the code in result manages to get the output.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to filter out Assign objects with Call properties? I notice the file parsing has Assign with Call and Name objects. I have updated the question.

Comment: Do not worry if you cannot answer the question, I will revert it to the original and maintain yours as the correct answer.

Comment: @Zysora In that case what should be the final dictionary?

Comment: Similar to the original one, I just want to get all assignments but filter out the ones that have value = Call. This is because when I use your method, I get the error: AttributeError: 'Call' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: @Zysora To avoid the `Call` node you can change the condition to `if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and (not isinstance(node.value, ast.Call))`

Answer (score 1):

One problem with a simple `isinstance` check for standalone `ast.Call`  objects as assignment values is that it is quite possible that the value of the assignment statement might not be a single call, but a combination of a call, operator, etc. As such, you can use a recursive function to check if an `ast` object contains an `ast.Call` object at any depth:

```
import ast
s = """
def isMaskedArray(x):
    isarray = isMaskedArray
    masked_array = MaskedArray
    ignore_val = x + y()
    ignore_val1 = val[fun()]
    a, [b, c], [[d], e, [d]] = something

_ShapeType = TypeVar("_ShapeType", bound=Any)
"""
def has_call(tree):
   return isinstance(tree, ast.Call) or any(has_call(j) for k in getattr(tree, '_fields', []) for j in 
        (getattr(tree, k) if isinstance(getattr(tree, k), list) else [getattr(tree, k)]))

r = {ast.unparse(i.targets[0]):ast.unparse(i.value) for i in ast.walk(ast.parse(s)) 
      if isinstance(i, ast.Assign) and not has_call(i)}
```

Output:

```
{'isarray': 'isMaskedArray', 'masked_array': 'MaskedArray', '(a, [b, c], [[d], e, [d]])': 'something'}
```